# Ошибка при отправке HTTP POST запроса

Tags: c#, .net, http, .net-standard

Есть некий сайт, который не предоставляет открытое API. но мне очень хочется им воспользоваться. Я задействовал для этого браузер Google Chrome с его инструментами разработчика, а так же расширение Restlet Client для тестирования api.

Так как я не очень шарю в теме, пришлось поплясать с бубном и в итоге я получил нужный ответ от API. Для этого мне пришлось прикрутить к запросу различные headers (типа User-Agent, Cookie и кастомный X-Token), которые я посмотрел в инструментах разработчика при обращении сайта к своим API. А так же в BODY запроса нужно было добавить JSON с параметрами запроса.

Но вот когда я решил создать запрос в любимом шарпе, API стали возвращать ошибку.

```
var http = new HttpClient();
var req = new HttpRequestMessage
{
    RequestUri = new Uri("http://***"),
};
req.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("X-Token", "someValue");
req.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Cookie", "someValue");
req.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Referer", "someValue");
req.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36");
req.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Origin", "someValue");
req.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "*/*");
req.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
req.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Language", "ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4");
req.Content = new StringContent("someValue", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

req.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
var resp = await http.SendAsync(req);
var res = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
return res;
```

Суть в том, что я добавил в запрос все, что находится у меня в запросе в расширении Restlet Client. Но ответ приходит такой же, как приходил в данном расширении, пока я не заполнил BODY (content) запроса нужными параметрами. Поэтому у меня есть подозрение, что я как то не правильно формирую Content.

Есть у кого мысли по этому поводу?

Comment: Это очень легко проверить - посмотри текст итогового запроса и сравни с тем, что ты вручную отправляешь.

P.S. Ты уверен, что куки не протухли?

Comment: @LunarWhisper, во первых вручную я отправляю так же через приложение (расширение браузера)... то есть я заполняю хедеры, заполняю боди... Текст боди я тупо скопировал и вставил. Куки вряд ли протухли, потому что я с теми же куками потом отправляю запрос через расширение и все норм возвращается